# How can I pass flags to this function more efficiently in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to be able to perform a text search where the user can choose which [flags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html#FindFlag-enum) to set before performing the search. Currently, I have a bunch of if/else statements that performs different searches based on the set flags. Is there a way to simplify this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
void FindDialog::on_btn_find_clicked()
{
    const QString find_term = ui->le_find->text();
    bool found;
    getConditions();

    //direction: true -> go backward, false -> go forward
    if(dir)
    {
        //area: true -> description area, false -> example area
        if(area)
            found = te_desc_ptr->find(find_term, QTextDocument::FindBackward);
        else
            found = te_code_ptr->find(find_term, QTextDocument::FindBackward);
    } else {
        if(area)
            found = te_desc_ptr->find(find_term);
        else
            found = te_code_ptr->find(find_term);
    }

    this->close();

}

void FindDialog::getConditions()
{
    //check conditions
    //Area: True = Description, False = Example
    //Direction: True = Up, False = Down
    area = ui->rbtn_desc->isChecked();
    dir = ui->rbtn_up->isChecked();
    case_sen = ui->cbx_case->isChecked();
    whole = ui->cbx_whole->isChecked();
    regx = ui->cbx_reg->isChecked();
}
```

The code looks if the user selected a checkbox and chooses which kind of search to perform. I'd really like to simplify the code so that there are less find() statements. Obviously, if I add more options, then there will be more if/else statements. How can I go about changing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collapse the `if` tree down to this:

```
auto textArea = area ? te_desc_ptr : te_code_ptr;
auto findFlags = dir ? QTextDocument::FindBackward : QTextDocument::FindFlags(0);
textArea->find(find_term, findFlags);
```

I'd also consider renaming `area` and `dir`, as it's not at all obvious what they signify just from their names.

Comment: Thanks, but Qt does not like "0" as a flag.